# How do I get the first date of a quarter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

The code that I have so far is below: I'm trying to find out what to put in place of my ?'s to find the start date of the quarter the date lies in.

```
SELECT
 QUARTER(r.callDate) AS quar,
 YEAR(r.callDate) AS ryear,
 ???????? AS scoreDateStart,
 (SELECT DATE (DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CONCAT( YEAR( r.callDate ), '-01-01'), INTERVAL QUARTER(r.callDate) QUARTER ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) AS scoreDateEnd,
 group_concat(DISTINCT(r.resultId) separator ', ') AS resultIds
FROM results AS r
GROUP BY  quar, ryear
ORDER BY quar;
```

I have tried Googling but to no avail.

An example of the output would be:

```
'1', '2012', '2012-01-01', '2012-03-31', '57, 58, 59'
'2', '2012', '2012-04-01', '2012-06-30', '10549, 10551, 12598'
```

Comment: Can you add example(s) of expected output?

Comment: Good Idea Jocelyn, thanks! I've edited my post to include an example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try this:

To get the start date of the current quarter use this:

```
  SELECT  MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER 
                                       - INTERVAL    1 QUARTER
```

So your Query would be:

```
SELECT
 QUARTER(r.callDate) AS quar,
 YEAR(r.callDate) AS ryear,
 MAKEDATE(YEAR(r.callDate), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(r.callDate) QUARTER -
  INTERVAL 1 QUARTER  AS scoreDateStart,
 (SELECT DATE (DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CONCAT( YEAR( r.callDate ), '-01-01'), 
 INTERVAL QUARTER(r.callDate) QUARTER ), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) AS scoreDateEnd,
 group_concat(DISTINCT(r.resultId) separator ', ') AS resultIds
FROM results AS r
GROUP BY  quar, ryear
ORDER BY quar;
```

Comment: I think that has done the trick, I'm just testing it now. Thanks Joe!

Comment: This can be generalized to find the start date of a quarter other than the current date, by changing CURDATE() for a date string.

Comment: If you need the last day of the current quarter, subtract by `INTERVAL 1 DAY` instead of `INTERVAL 1 QUARTER`.