# Date of first day in the current quarter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Using current_date in MySQL to get today's date, I want to get the current quarter first day date.

- Input: 2022-11-01
- Output: 2022-10-01
- Sample Code

  SELECT CURRENT_DATE; *(result: YYYY-MM-DD format)*
- I want to get the current quarter first day's date.
  If today's date is **2022-11-09** then current quarter will be October(Q4) and it's first day's date would be **2022-10-01** (1st October)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the first date of a quarter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884618/how-do-i-get-the-first-date-of-a-quarter-in-mysql)

Comment: I came up with this at last. Hope this might help somebody.
select cast(date_trunc('quarter', cur_date)as date) as quarter_firstDate from 
              (select current_date as cur_date)

Comment: That's no correct syntax for MYSQL which you taged as your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QUARTER` function which is a part of MySQL.

This returns you the number of current quarter. Than you can use `MAKEDATE` to construct your date.

```
SELECT 
  MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
```

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to mark this as an answer.